# Can records have capitalized fields?

Tags: syntax, record, capitalization, purescript

In purescript, `{foo :: Foo}` desugars to `Record ("foo" :: Foo)`, as far as my understanding goes. Could I make something like `Record ("F" :: Foo)`? How would that look in record access syntax? Would `thing.F` be syntactically valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting fields is exactly the way to do it, both in the type:

```
type MyRecord = { "Usually impossible field name" :: Boolean }
```

And in accessors / patterns:

```
make :: Boolean -> MyRecord
make = { "Usually impossible field name": _ }

get :: MyRecord -> Boolean
get = _."Usually impossible field name"

update :: MyRecord -> Boolean -> MyRecord
update = _ { "Usually impossible field name" = _ }
```

Quoting fields this way allows you to name the record fields whatever you want, using caps, symbols, numbers, etc.

This is a little similar to `obj["property"]` in JavaScript, but you can only use string literals for the property name rather than arbitrary values.